# Tizen:Where can we find the implementation code for Tizen::Ui::SystemUtil::GenerateKeyEvent?

Tags: window-managers, tizen

I would like to know how the key event is read and dispatched from the kernel to the Tizen OS. Haven't found any informative document on the same. While surfing through Tizen wiki I came across Tizen::Ui::SystemUtil::GenerateKeyEvent function which says it generates a key event. I would like to see the implementation of this function and understand how the key event is generated and injected into the input queue. 
Please let me know where can we find the source code of this implementation. Also, point me to,if any, documentation is available that gives information about the event propagation from keypress till it reaches the application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for `Tizen::Ui::SystemUtil::GenerateKeyEvent` is found [here](https://review.tizen.org/git/?p=framework/osp/uifw.git;a=blob;f=src/ui/FUiSystemUtil.cpp;h=2f041902ffc5fb626eafd534a8a087763124d16c;hb=refs/heads/tizen_2.1#l42). It in turn calls the `SystemUtilImpl` version of `GenerateKeyEvent`, which you can find [here](https://review.tizen.org/git/?p=framework/osp/uifw.git;a=blob;f=src/ui/FUi_SystemUtilImpl.cpp;h=df02b15c9a5da26c7feb4c57690817650572feb3;hb=refs/heads/tizen_2.1#l174).

Comment: Hi Michael, I tried using that API in my sample native application and got the error "INVALID_PRIVILEGES" error. I found that we need to have platform privilege for it. I didn't get anywhere regarding the steps or procedure for getting this privilege. It says it is given for Tizen App developers. Please let me know the procedure if you know how I can get this privilege.

Comment: From the Tizen Security Architecture page: "These privileges are open **only to a specific set** of Tizen application developers". In other words, you'll probably have to apply for them with the Tizen Association (or whoever the governing body is) and present a good reason for why you'd need that privilege. I don't know what the procedure is for this.